# II have a running stream of integers, how can I take print the sum of last k element elements from this stream at any point of time

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a running stream of integers, how can I print the sum of last k elements from this stream at any point in time.

For example:

```
1,2,3,7,8,0,1,4,5 ....
k = 4
answer = 0 + 1 + 4 + 5  = 10
```

what would be the optimal data structure or approach?

Comment: When you say "stream", what do you mean? Are these numbers coming from a file, or stdin, or a function call, or...?

Comment: As an abstract problem, the implication is that you need to write an "online" algorithm which is able to answer two queries: (1) observe new integer, and (2) report sum of last k integers observed.

Comment: Stream means the stream of integers. it doesn't matter it's from a file or STDIN or a function call or some online feature.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a double ended queue (`deque`).  Push new elements into one end until you have `k`, then pop them off the other as you push new ones on.

If you want to avoid iterating over the deque each time you need a sum, you can just keep a running total as a single `int`; subtract whatever you pop and add whatever you push.

Comment: The second sentence is the key (to this likely interview question :) )

Comment: Note that if `k` isn't a constant, then you need to just grow the queue forever so you can be able to sum an arbitrarily long slice off the end.  In that case I think a normal list is fine.

Comment: You should only pop them off the other end when the deque contains k elements; you don't want to subtract anything before you've seen more than k integers.

Comment: By the way, in the abstract, the solution only needs a queue, it doesn't have to be double-ended; but `deque` happens to be the most efficient queue data structure in Python's standard library if you don't need concurrency.

Comment: The question asked for "optimal" so efficiency is indeed a consideration.  :)  A normal Python list incurs an O(n) performance hit when you push/pop the first element because it's array-backed, which is why deque exists.